# How to debug a WCF service with two console applications simultaneously

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I have a WCF web service which is responsible for managing work sent from our internal business applications to a distributed set of client applications.

I would like to be able to setup a console application to mock a internal application (to test sending work) as well as one to mock a client application (to test performing the work).

To do so, I would need to debug two console applications at the same time with the ability to step through code within the WCF service.  Obviously [incorrect, see awswer], a Visual Studio solution can only have exactly one startup project; stepping through in that scenario is easy-peasy.  But how can I step through the WCF service with TWO console applications at the same time?  (Can/should it be done?  Is there a better way to approach testing?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Obviously, a Visual Studio solution can only have exactly one startup project;

This is not true.

If you right click on the solution in Solution Explorer, and choose "Set StartUp Projects...", there is the option to have *Multiple Startup Projects*.  This allows you to start both console applications in the debugger when you hit Debug.

Answer (score 1):

See Reed copsey's answer, but I would add that you can also run two copies of Visual Studio at the same time.  Just load the solution into each instance of visual studio, set up your break points in the respective copy of visual studio and press run in each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug multiple projects from the same solution just by right clicking them each and selecting Debug/Start New Instance.
Alternatively, go to solution properties and select multiple startup projects.

However, in such situations I wouldn't debug all three apps at once since it's very hard to keep track of things. At most two at once and that's hard too for bigger projects, in high concurrency scenarios. 
But nothing wrong if you have a small project.

In a real situation I would rely on debug logging. Lots and lots of debug logging. To file or event log, doesn't matter. If done properly and in the right places it will offer information close to a manual debug session. It can help you track down all kinds of issues. Hope this helps.